# Set defaults for generator per application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Is there way to set a default flag for all generator commands in a specific app?**

With Rubygems you can save the --no-rdoc to the .gemrc file and it will then apply that to all your gem commands later.

Can you do this with rails generate, so that a flag, such as --no-stylesheets is applied to all rails g scaffold commands for the life of that app?

```
rails g scaffold Model field field2 field3 --no-stylesheets
```

If I'm using boostrap/foundation I know from the very beginning I don't want that ever generated for the app, seems a waste to have to type it every time.

Comment: `config.generators.stylesheets = false
config.generators.javascripts = false` add in application.rb and it will not generate stylesheets and javascripts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generators can be configured in application.rb, in the `config.generators` block, in particular

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.stylesheets false
end
```

Will suppress generation of stylesheets. You can read about the other options available in the [configuring rails applications](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-generators) guide.

Comment: The config.generators block goes back to 3.0 I think. Not sure how long the stylesheets option has been there but it is described in the 3.2 version of the configuring rails app guide

Answer (score 2):

```
config.generators.stylesheets = false 
config.generators.javascripts = false
```

OR

```
config.generators.assets = false
```

OR

```
rails g controller foo --skip-assets
```

add to application.rb

Comment: this was a good answer, but I marked the other since this one is deprecated now.

Comment: you can check other one